# Pandas Dataframe Column Indexing

Tags: python, pandas

```
sample_data=data.text[50]
```

data is the name of dataframe.

text is column name.

My ques is [50] will take first 50 characters from each row of text column?

Comment: Nope, it gets 50th row value from `text` column. Simple example, `s = pd.Series([1,2,3]); print(s[0])` -> `0`...`print(s[1])`-> `1`, `print(s[2])`->`2`.

Comment: Removed `data-science` tag as it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: To get 1st 50 characters use `data.text.str[:50]`

Comment: To get 50 characters from each row.text, you can combine above answer with apply() or with iterrows(). Something like `data.apply(lambda row: row['text'][:50],axis=1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it gets 50th row value from text column.To get 1st 50 characters use data.text.str[:50]

--- @Ch3steR